# Change CSS to Mat-Form-Field with Search Box inside it

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using `Angular` and `Angular Material` along with `SCSS`

In the front-end, I am using the code below...

```
<mat-form-field  class="custom-form-field" style="padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 0px; line-height: 0px;">
    <input style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" matInput type="text" id="onSearch" (keyup)="keyUp($event)">
    <mat-icon matPrefix class="centered-icon">search</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

With this code, it appears black bold outline for the textbox when I hover over the Search box and blue bold outline when I click inside the search box as below..

[image: Search Black Box]

[image: Search Blue Box]

Tried applying the `CSS` as below..

```
.mat-form-field input:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

But it is not working...

How to make this appear like a normal textbox like below..

[image: Search bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below CSS seems to do the job, we can use `border-color`, `color` and `caret-color` to set the border to always be `black`!

I was not getting the border for the mat form field, so I added `appearance="outline"` to get the outside border!

```
<mat-form-field
  appearance="outline"
  class="custom-form-field"
  style="padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 0px; line-height: 0px;"
>
  <input
    style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;"
    matInput
    type="text"
    id="onSearch"
  />
  <mat-icon matPrefix class="centered-icon">search</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

styles.css

```
.custom-form-field .mat-form-field-outline-thick,
.custom-form-field
  .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused
  .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
  border-color: black !important;
  color: black !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.custom-form-field .mat-input-element {
  caret-color: black !important;
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uzrwey?file=test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Findex.html,test%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.scss) -> `cd test` -> `npm i` -> `npm run start`

Comment: Updated the Question. How to make it appear like a normal textbox?

Comment: @CPK_2011 please ask a new question this is the answer for the question asked originally