# Search Bar Highlighting on focus of the Mat-Form-Field Input Box in Angular HTML

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am following this Question in Stackoverflow...

[Textbox Highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77897821/change-css-to-mat-form-field-with-search-box-inside-it)

[image: Expected Search Box]

I would like to have the same highlighting for the Search Box which has this code..

```
<mat-form-field  class="custom-form-field" appearance="outline" style="padding-top: 5px;padding-bottom: 0px; line-height: 0px;">
    <input style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;" matInput type="text" id="onSearch" (keyup)="keyUp($event)">
    <mat-icon matPrefix class="centered-icon">search</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

And it's `CSS` code is as below..

```
.custom-form-field .mat-form-field-outline-thick,
.custom-form-field
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused
.mat-form-field-outline-thick {
    border-color: #ced4da !important;
    border-width: 0px !important;

    color: #ced4da !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
.custom-form-field .mat-input-element {
    caret-color: #ced4da !important;
    color: #575e64;
}
.custom-form-field .mat-form-field-infix {
    border-top: 0px !important;
    padding: 0.9em 0 0.6em 0 !important;
}
.custom-form-field .mat-form-field-prefix {
    top: -1px !important;
    color: #575e64;
}
.custom-form-field .mat-form-field-outline-start,
.custom-form-field .mat-form-field-outline-end,
.custom-form-field .mat-form-field-outline-gap {
    border-width: 1px !important;
}
```

The highlighting in blue color happens without applying any styles to the input textbox. But, if I convert that input textbox to mat-form-field, the hightlighting goes away with the current code.

Atleast converting from `Angular Material` form field to textbox is also okay for me...

Comment: @Naren-Murali - Please help me on this...

Comment: Is there any way to implement normal text box with search icon inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the CSS for [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) for this requirement. we can use `outline: #bfdeff solid 2px !important;`

CSS

```
.custom-form-field .mat-form-field-outline-thick,
.custom-form-field
  .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused
  .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
  border-color: #ced4da !important;
  border-width: 0px !important;

  color: #ced4da !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
  outline: #bfdeff solid 2px !important;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.custom-form-field .mat-input-element {
  caret-color: #ced4da !important;
  color: #575e64;
}
.custom-form-field .mat-form-field-infix {
  border-top: 0px !important;
  padding: 0.9em 0 0.6em 0 !important;
}
.custom-form-field .mat-form-field-prefix {
  top: -1px !important;
  color: #575e64;
}
.custom-form-field .mat-form-field-outline-start,
.custom-form-field .mat-form-field-outline-end,
.custom-form-field .mat-form-field-outline-gap {
  border-width: 1px !important;
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ntvcuf?file=test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.scss) -> `cd test` -> `npm i` -> `npm run start`